# Is there a UnivMap equivilant in Rust?

Tags: data-structures, rust, types, ocaml

In OCaml, there is a construct called [`univ_map.t`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.55.00/tmp/core_kernel/Std_kernel.Univ_map.html). The idea is you can create unique ids, that are genericed over a type `'a`. Then, the `univ_map` allows you to map from those keys to values also of type `'a`s. [Here](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/example-use-of-core-kernel-univ-map/4572/3) is an example.

The thing that makes these `univ_map`s special is that they allow you to store values with many different types in the same dictionary, where you retain type safety because the key of the dictionary tells you what type you're getting out.

Is there a construct that would allow me to do something similar in Rust? I know in OCaml they are implemented with [open variants](https://ocaml.org/manual/extensiblevariants.html), which I don't believe Rust has.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to ask for direct equivalents of some construct from one language in another since there rarely is one. There's usually a lot of nuance to constructs like this, and it's not at all clear what is and is not important for you. You should instead ask for a specific use case, then reference a specific solution in another language if you like, but odds are that solutions in other languages will be very different. They're different languages for a reason, after all.

Comment: You should probably clarify that by `'a` you are not talking about the Rust syntax for lifetimes but the OCaml syntax for generic types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with OCaml, but looking at the docs:

> [`Univ_map`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.55.00/tmp/core_kernel/Univ_map.html): Universal/heterogeneous maps [...] useful for storing values of arbitrary type in a single map [...] built on top of `Univ`.
>
> [`Univ`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/109.55.00/tmp/core_kernel/Univ.html): An extensible universal variant type. Every type id corresponds to one branch of the variant type.

The closest thing that Rust has that sounds like `Univ` is the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait, which is designed to represent any type (with exceptions). However, there is no standard type for storing a collection of `Any`s that is accessed by its [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html). From looking how popular crates handle this, its usually a bespoke wrapper around `HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>` or similar. I hope I've understood correctly.

Comment: Another aspect of "universal values" is that you can create multiple unique `TypeId`s for the same type, so that you can store multiple values of the same type and still distinguish them. No idea if that's also requested here though.

Comment: I think you have; that answer makes it seem like it's not possible to do what I want in Rust. A critical feature of the TypeId in OCaml is that it's parameterized over another type, that can be used so the compiler knows what types is coming out of the .get function.

Comment: @ZevMinsky-Primus What do you mean by parameterised here? In Rust `A<B>` is a distinct type from `A<C>` and all types that satisfy `'static` have a `TypeId`. The `TypeId` itself is not parameterised, but parameterised types should have unique `TypeId`s

Comment: @ZevMinsky-Primus typically the API would have the `.get` parameterized by the type you're trying to get like this: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45a44bcdeabd0f7aee0bb9681f4ba0b4). Does that help? Or is this not what you were after? If not, I'd suggest following the advice in one of the comments and include the exact behavior you're looking for in your post.